# How to disable deep freeze using registry/by deleting DFServEX.exe?

Tags: deep-freeze

I just want to learn how to disable deepfreeze from windows without clicking shift+double click on deep freeze logo? I want to disable it by registry hacking or by deleting DFServEX.exe proccess. Please somebody help me to learn this tricks.

Comment: Its not possible to disable deepfreeze in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Deep Freeze is a kernel level driver.  In some ways it is similar to a [Rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) in that it will permit you to delete or change things that would seem to remove it, but you aren't actually doing that.

Short of occasional bugs, you can't remove Deep Freeze without the password.  The main solution is just to format/reinstall the entire system.

Comment: Can i format C drive in deep freeze mode?If yes than how?

Comment: @powermun50 - You will be unable to format any drive that is under the protected by Deep Freeze.